# Calling a function declared in a class

Tags: vb.net, function, class, button

Hello i am looking for some help. I have created a class and have added a function inside of it and now i want to use the function as the event of a button.

```
Public Class Professor
    Inherits Person

    Public m_publications As Integer

    Public Function IsOutstanding() As Boolean
        If m_publications >= 100 Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return m_publications
    End Function
End Class
```

and so that when you click on the button the result pops up in a `messagebox`

Comment: Please, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: that code will not compile using Option Strict.  `Return Return m_publications` is nonsense for a boolean function.  all that needs to be in that function is `Return (m_publications >= 100)`, but to use it: `Dim myProf As New Professor()` presumably somewhere it is told who this guy is including the number of pubs.  then `If myProf.IsOutstanding() Then...`